# Generate possible combinations and get first 50 only

Tags: python, combinations

I'm looking for a way to get the first 50 only of the possible combinations (20 in fixed length) with conditions but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I have an example below.

```
import itertools
a = array([1,2,5])
b = array([8,9,10])
c = 0
if c == 1:
  x = a
  y = b
else:
  x = b
  y = a
mylist = list(itertools.product(x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y))
```

My output would be:

```
(8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1)
(8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 2)
(8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 5)
(8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 2 8 1)
(8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 2 8 2)
(8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 1 8 2 8 5)
.
.
```

and so on..

I already encountered memory error. I think this has too many combinations, so I just want to get the first 50 only. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your arrays should be declared as: `a = array('l', [1,2,5])`. Also, are you sure the memory issues are from this piece of code? (`itertools` produces iterators which should be efficient).

Comment: @adrianp - `itertools` are efficient when used element after element, not converted into a list at once.

Comment: @eumiro right, I missed that

Comment: Instead of `x,y,x,y..` etc, you could use `product(*([x,y]*10))`.  This makes the list `[x,y,x,y,...]` and then the `*` basically turns `product([x,y,x,y..])` into `product(x,y,x,y..)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stay with `itertools`, use [`islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
list(itertools.islice(itertools.product(x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y), 50))
```

this takes the first 50 elements from the `product` and converts them into a list.